# Kiosk mode issues

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Please find the below code

**test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=help", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,width=600,height=400,left=600,top=500,status=yes,scrollbars=no,resize=no")
      return;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working in Edge normal mode but its not working in Edge kiosk mode.

**KIOSK MODE:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk C:\Users\10637\Desktop\test.html  --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen
```

In Edge with Fullscreen Kiosk mode  when we click on a button that takes you to a web page  opens within the edge window and you can never navigate out of it or leave the page. Is there a way to force edge in Kiosk mode to open  in a new window

Could you please help us to resolve issues

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in Kiosk mode, Edge is not able to open sites in a new window, because such action is blocked. You can check [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#kiosk-mode-supported-features) and you'll find **CTRL+N blocked (open a new window)**. I'm afraid you cannot force Edge in Kiosk mode to open in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the kiosk mode. Try it public browsing.

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk C:\Users\10637\Desktop\test.html  --edge-kiosk-type=public-browsing
```